# Fixed Header when the Div above is scrolled past

Tags: javascript, jquery, header, fixed

I have this setup so that when the page is scrolled 400px the #headermenu becomes fixed. However the div above this one will have a variable height depending on the screen size.

I need the JS to make the #headermenu become fixed when the bottom of the div above it(#mixedheightheader) has reached the top of the window.

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/Deanr1976/yLon2oj3/6/)

Thanks in advance for you help

```
<div id="mixedheightheader"></div>
```

```js
$(function() {    
  $('#headermenu');
});

$(window).scroll(function() {    
  if ($(document).scrollTop() < 400)     {        
    if ($('#headermenu'))         {            
      $('#headermenu');            
      $('#headermenu').stop().css({
        top: '0',
        position: 'relative'
      });        
    }    
  }    
  else     {        
    if ($('#headermenu'))         {            
      $('#headermenu');            
      $('#headermenu').stop().css({
        top: '0',
        position: 'fixed'
      });        
    }      
  }
});
```

```css
body {
  height: 3000px
}

#headermenu {
  width: 100%;
  background: black;
  min-height: 100px;
}

#mixedheightheader {
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  min-height: 200px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: grey;
  clear: both;
}

#below {
  width: 100%;
  background: darkgrey;
  height: 100px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="mixedheightheader"></div>
<div id="headermenu"></div>
<div id="below"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have updated you fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/yLon2oj3/11/

```
$(function() {    
  var isFixed = false; //This is to not fix if already fixed and reverse

    $(window).scroll(function() {
    var mixedHeightHeader = $('#mixedheightheader');
    //This uses the offset top position and the height to calculate the bottom of your variable header
    var mixedHeightHeaderBottom = mixedHeightHeader.offset().top + mixedHeightHeader.height();
    var headerMenu = $('#headermenu');


    if ($(document).scrollTop() < mixedHeightHeaderBottom && isFixed)       {        
        if (headerMenu) {                  
        headerMenu.css({
            top: '0',
            position: 'relative'
        });  
        isFixed = false;
        //this is to remove the placeholder space of the fixed top nav, when its not fixed to top
        mixedHeightHeader.css('margin-bottom', '0');
      }    
    }    
    else  if ($(document).scrollTop() > mixedHeightHeaderBottom && !isFixed)   {        
      if (headerMenu) {                      
        headerMenu.css({
          top: '0',
          position: 'fixed'
        });
        //This holds the position that was occupied by the fixed top nav when it was a relative element, because its now taken out of the flow.
        mixedHeightHeader.css('margin-bottom', headerMenu.height() + 'px');
      }
      isFixed = true;
    }
    });

});
```

Comment: I could kiss you! Thank you!

Comment: Done a lot of work around fixed to top navs last year. :) Happy to help.

Comment: It's delayed on mobile devices until you release your finder from the screen. Is there a way around this

Comment: You probably dont need that stop() in between, also you could add a flag called is fixed, which can be used as additional condition for both the if and else parts so that the whole fixing or unfixing code doesnt run unless it has to.